# Does a temporarily suspended account automatically unaccept answers to their questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, account-suspension, unaccepted-answer

The user [Ram Dutt Shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591061/ram-dutt-shukla) was recently suspended temporarily due to "voting irregularities".

I had previously answered [one of this user's questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815602/not-able-to-put-the-values-in-the-mdc), which had been accepted.

Then I lost 15 reputation points for my answer being unaccepted, which I assumed was an action performed by the user. On viewing the user's profile, however, I notice the suspension.

So does the temporary suspension automatically unaccept answers that were previously accepted by the user, and do I automatically lose reputation points because of it?

Comment: No, it was the only question that the user unaccepted.

Comment: Does the unaccept contribute to the user's "voting irregularities"?

Comment: I doubt it. Otherwise, the unaccept timestamp would have been closer to the when the votes were reversed.

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume it *should* contribute to the "irregularities"?

Comment: Not objectively. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted above, a suspension does not affect the user's Accepts (given nor received, actually). The user manually unaccepted your answer a little over 10 hours before they were suspended.

An unaccept could, in some cases, be one bit of evidence in irregularities. Sometimes a cheating user might suddenly switch an accept from a legitimate answer to one written by a sock they are using to cheat, but that did not happen here, and it's not really a big thing overall.

Finally, as a side note; sometimes a vote irregularity suspension can indirectly cause loss of reputation to legitimate users: when sock puppets are deleted, *all* of their votes are invalidated, no matter to whom. I've lost reputation myself from removing someone else's sock puppets, before!